# Ionic sidemenu not working after login, goes back to the login page instead

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I have a login page where I disable the sidemenu with:

```
 ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
 }
 ionViewDidLeave() {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(true);
 }
```

After logging in, I navigate to / which goes to /welcome:

```
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
```

In /welcome, I have the menu turned on:

```
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(true);
  }
```

Using Edge/Chrome, when I try to use the side-menu after logging in, it instead tries to "Go Back" to the login page:

[image: Slider Example Problem]

Added: If I refresh the page after on /welcome, it reloads the page and fixes the sidemenu. So whatever is happening it seems like it must be left over from the login screen's functionality. Also, I thought adding ion-header fixed it, worked for about 2 logins then suddenly went back to it's previous behavior.

I've also noticed that if I sign out, the Angular authguard sends it back to /login, but if I try to swipe while on the login page, it tries to take me back to the app as though I was authenticated.. Then when I click on a link the Auth guard does it's job and sends be back to login again.

This time, I can still swipe left but a blank page tries to appear from the left instead - and this happens in desktop mode too.

[image: Blank page when trying to use the sidebar on the login page]

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: I think it is a hierarchy problem in the views, it is not known who is the father and who is the son, the side menu is a parent element and always the authentication must be in a separate module for security. 

Could you upload an app that allows me to debug and help you with the problem?

Comment: @JonathanDuarte I can create a quick sample app and provide a link for you - but until then you should know that it's simply the boilerplate code created by ionic, and I just created another screen and disabled the menu. It is using an AuthGuard to forward to the page, maybe that's it? When I disabled the Ionic "Swipeback" feature it behaves properly, but on IOS with gestures it still acts strange. In another app, I used window.location instead of Navigate to overcome the issue which of course isn't ideal.

Comment: Perfect provide me the link to reproduce the issue and I will be happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

I thought adding ion-header fixed it, it did at first, then suddenly started doing it again.

I finally ended up disabling Swipe within Ionic with:
IonicModule.forRoot({ swipeBackEnabled: false})

If anyone has any info it'd be appreciated.